# UVUnwrap splitting other edges besides seams

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm coming from 3DS Max and I am having issues unwrapping my model. I marked the seams, as I would have in 3DS Max but when I go to unwrap, the edges that I want to keep together split. I've tried all the unwrap options but all seem to do the same thing. How do I go about just unwrapping faces but keeping all edges that aren't marked as seams together?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an edge isn't marked with a seam it will be kept together when using the standard 'Unwrap' tool *as long as the geometry is connected*. From your screenshot it looks like you have some extra faces between the two blue faces you have selected (the black dots are 'face-dots'), which could mean the faces aren't actually connected; outlined in red here:

[image]

Select all the faces in the mesh with <kbd>A</kbd> (press <kbd>A</kbd> again if it deselects everything) and choose *Mesh> Vertices> Remove Doubles*:

[image]

This will remove any vertices that are extremely close to each other and should remove those extra faces, meaning your geometry is properly connected.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realise the added face. Must have pressed 'e' by accident and extruded it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to go to edge select mode and only select the edge where you want to have a cut (dont select the whole face). this way blender will split this edge and create your seem.

For simple geometric objects you also just hit space and time "smart uv". this way blender creates your uv map automatically