# Split Faces in UV Mapping

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

For some reason faces in UV Editing are glued to each other. How do I split them from eachother?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56270/uvunwrap-splitting-other-edges-besides-seams?rq=1

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3318/34004 answered my question. The top answer is no good.

Answer (score 0):

Mark the seams yourself in Edit Mode.

Press ctrl+e and mark seams (seams are like the cutting edges for UVs). Then unwrap the UV again.

Comment: Doesn't work lol

Comment: Did you Mark the seams in object mode in the object itself ? You also have to make new uvs then

Comment: I thought I should mark it in UV mode. Edited accordingly. This method is much quicker though https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3317/separate-selected-uv-map-vertices-from-surrounding-vertices/3318#3318 Although I agree with you that one should plan in advance and mark the seams accordingly.